# MS Exchange, get room events without full AD permissions

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Right now I can get a list of all rooms from Exchange. That will give me the ID and room name. However, if i try to use the following code to access the events that is planned for the room, I get access denied. (My permissions are not enough).

```
FolderId RoomMailboxCalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "room@domain.com");
CalendarView cvCalView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(31));
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = service.FindAppointments(RoomMailboxCalendarFolderId, cvCalView);
```

If I open Outlook, press Calendar, then click on **New Appointment -> Scheduling Assistant and Add Rooms**... I see a list of the events in that room even though I apparently don't have enough permissions from the above code.

How is the data fetched for that preview if I don't have permission to read from the room calendar?

Answer (score 0):

GetUserAvailblity is what is used in Outlook in the Scheduling assistant to do this so you can do the same in EWS see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532567(v=exchg.80).aspx

cheers
Glen